# Mutiplication support for jquery Calculation

Tags: jquery, multiplication

I would like to know how to add support for multiplication in this jQuery solution:
[jquery calculation question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239760/jquery-calculation-question)

It works well for addition and substraction, but how can it support multiplication?

thanks.

You can see the code example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/JRcqk/1/

Comment: Having a good laugh at the expense of other developers, aren't you?

Comment: Nope. that was a valid question. I am new to jQuery so I am the one people should laugh at.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, see what the developers did on the other question and try to apply it to multiplication **yourselves**, and if you get stuck anywhere, then post your problem. Just saying, that's a better way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You would need some changes in the logic, and also use the [dreaded `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil) .. (*if you want an agnostic way of handling the calculations*)

```
$('#Selection').change(calc); //update result when changing the number
$("#number").keyup(calc);     //update result when select changes

function calc() {
  $('#result').val( eval( $('#number').val() + $("#Selection").val() ) );
}
```

and HTML

```
<div>
    <input id="number" type="text" />

    <select id="Selection" name="D1"> 
    <option value="+1">Plus 1</option>
    <option value="-1">Minus 1</option>
    <option value="*2">double</option>
    <option value="/2">half</option>

    </select>

    <input id="result" type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to avoid the eval function if you use a switch statement and go throguh the values. check this: 
[switch statement in Jquery and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435012/switch-statement-in-jquery-and-list)

Also the solution that Meder proposed was good.

@Gaby - your solution will not perform the addition properly. it will just concatenate both numbers unless you use the parseInt().

@Anurag - It is in the interest of everyone to keep place positive. If you don not wish to contribute to a question then keep going. don't just stop and hurl comments that do not contribute to the question. That does not do any good to the community.